# jdeveloper: versioning tool - xml-source-compare

Tags: jdeveloper

I'm using the versioning tool in jdeveloper.
before commit a file i'm checking the changes in file history-> xml-source-compare.
for some reason I don't get used to the display of the difference, it's not enough clearly for me.
I always worked with "compare it" software.
I would like to know if there is any way to define that the xml-source-compare will use "compare it" software instead of the existing software.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the tool used. You can however use an external SVN tool (or whatever source control you use) and set it up to use your merge tool.

Comment: Do you know how to set it up?

Comment: Well,  that depends on the software you use. Then you look into the help or docs...